# Symfony backend development

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am developing a website and I am using FosUserBundle. I would like to know if there is any bundle to manage the backend that it is easy to integrate with FosUserBundle and which is the best. Other question, why should I use a bundle to implement the backend instead of developing by myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which is the best is not a good question in this place, so this is only my personal opinion. That depend of what you need for your backend project, and how much of that was native included for the backend bundle, and also if the rest which is not included can be easily implemented following the selected bundle directives. I can recommend two of them.

1. [EasyAdminBundle](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle) Very simple backend construction and a lots of functionalities in an extremely short time. Can be integrated con FOSUser, so, the backend can be secured, but the kind of things like show different menus depending of roles, isn't already native implemented. Depending of the customization can be easy to extend.
2. [SonataAdminBundle](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/index.html) Very powerful but hard to configure. This is the boss of the backend bundles, you can do pretty much everything, but some times cost you a lot of work. Fully integrated with FOSUser.

Why use a backend bundle?, first you must check those two and figure out all the thing you can easily do, and compare the effort of do it from scratch.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

There  is some which integrates quite easily:

1. https://sonata-project.org/bundles/
2. https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle

There is nothing special about FOSUserBundle that has to be integrated. Most of the work is configuration.

I would suggest you to use any bundle to save time and to have tested and properly working, flexible backend zone.